# Add a model in the present in the other namespace as foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-5

In Rails I want to include a model_id as foreign key into another model which is present in another namespcae.
I have two models as
First:

```
class Garment < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Second:

```
class Superadmin::Company < ApplicationRecord
end
```

I am using the following command for it.

```
 rails g migration addCompanyIdToGarment company:references
```

which give output like:

```
class AddCompanyIdToGarment < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_foreign_key :garments, :company
  end
end
```

which is incorrect, please provide the correct command or procedure to do it.
The name of the tables in database is as:

```
superadmin_companies 
garments
```

Comment: is the table name of company in db superadmin_companies??

Comment: yes  table name in is db superadmin_companies

Answer (score 4):

Command to generate migration:

```
rails g migration addCompanyIdToGarment superadmin_company:references
```

Migration file:

```
class AddCompanyIdToGarment < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_reference :garments, :superadmin_company, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

Comment: If you added has_many and belongs_to associations in models then use below code:

   `superadmin_company = Superadmin::Company.find_by(id: params[:id])`

   `superadmin_company.garments`

Comment: It gives error:  Unknown column 'garments.company_id'

Comment: I have explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53942615/list-all-associated-model-records-present-in-another-model-present-in-another-na

Comment: Here foreign_key is superadmin_company_id in garments table.

Answer (score 0):

I have figure out a way ie.
Modify the migration as:

```
class AddCompanyIdToGarment < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_reference :garments, :superadmin_companies, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```