# List all associated model records present in another model present in another namespace in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two models like:

```
class Superadmin::Company < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :garments
end
```

2nd

```
class Garment < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :company ,:class_name => "Superadmin::Company"
end
```

But when I search like

```
company = Superadmin::Company.find(9)
company.garments
```

Its give error: as

```
 Garment Load (1.3ms)  SELECT `garments`.* FROM `garments` WHERE `garments`.`company_id` = 9 ORDER BY created_at asc
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'garments.company_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `garments`.* FROM `garments` WHERE `garments`.`company_id` = 9 ORDER BY created_at asc
    from /home/tukatech/rails_projects/live_tukagarments/.bundle/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:218:in `query'
```

Table names in database is as:

```
1. garments
2. superadmin_companies
```

please provide if there is a correct way to search using rails foreign key associations relation.

Data base is as:

```
mysql> desc superadmin_companies;
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name              | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| address           | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| phone             | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id           | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created_at        | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at        | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| logo_file_name    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| logo_content_type | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| logo_file_size    | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| logo_updated_at   | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> desc garments;
+--------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| xhtml_file_file_name     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| xhtml_file_content_type  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| xhtml_file_file_size     | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| xhtml_file_updated_at    | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| xhtml_thumb_file_name    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| xhtml_thumb_content_type | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| xhtml_thumb_file_size    | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| xhtml_thumb_updated_at   | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at               | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at               | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| category                 | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| garment_type             | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id                  | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| superadmin_company_id    | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the description mentioned in the post and the comments in one of the answers it seems like the relation defined in the models is unable to relate with the column names.

For it to work, please change to the one below:

```
class Superadmin::Company < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :garments, class_name: "Garment", foreign_key: "superadmin_company_id"
end
```

Now it will start mapping the with the foreign_key specified in the relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Update association as below:

```
class Superadmin::Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :garments, foreign_key: 'superadmin_company_id'
end

class Garment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company, class_name: 'Superadmin::Company', foreign_key: 'superadmin_company_id'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `company_id` column in the `garments` table. You have to add it via migration. Try:

```
rails generate migration AddCompanyToGarment company:references
```

Comment: superadmin_company_id is present in database

Comment: Oh, then you have to specify the _id field explicitly. Change the `belongs_to` association in `Garment` model to `belongs_to :company ,:class_name => "Superadmin::Company", :foreign_key => "superadmin_company_id"`